# Как отсортировать массива php по убыванию, ориентируясь на одно из значений?

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день, дорогие специалисты.

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как отсортировать массив по одному "столбику" его значений.
Допустим, я прочитал и создал массив размеров в N строк и 3 столбика. Например:
*

```
$arr[1][1]=Имя1;
$arr[1][2]=Фамилия2;
$arr[1][3]=7;
$arr[2][1]=Имя2;
$arr[2][1]=Фамилия";
$arr[2][1]=4;
```

В 3-м столбике находятся числа, вот именно по ним нужно отсортировать сей массив, чтобы из такого:

```
Имя1 | Фамилия1 | 7
Имя2 | Фамилия2 | 4
```

получить вот такой:

```
Имя2 | Фамилия2 | 4
Имя1 | Фамилия1 | 7
```

Надеюсь, я объяснил доступно. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: @Женька, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[array-multisort](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
$arr = array(
    '1' =>  array(
        '1' =>  'Имя1',
        '2' =>  'Фамилия1',
        '3' =>  '7'
    ),
    '2' =>  array(
        '1' =>  'Имя2',
        '2' =>  'Фамилия2',
        '3' =>  '4'
    ),
    '3' =>  array(
        '1' =>  'Имя3',
        '2' =>  'Фамилия3',
        '3' =>  '9'
    ),
    '4' =>  array(
        '1' =>  'Имя4',
        '2' =>  'Фамилия4',
        '3' =>  '1'
    )
);

$tmp = array(); 
foreach($arr as &$ma){
    $tmp[] = &$ma[3];
}
array_multisort($tmp, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Имя4
            [2] => Фамилия4
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Имя2
            [2] => Фамилия2
            [3] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Имя1
            [2] => Фамилия1
            [3] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Имя3
            [2] => Фамилия3
            [3] => 9
        )

)
```

[массивы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

Comment: А как добавить данные в этот массив?

Comment: Добавил ссылку в конец ответа

Answer (score -1):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

Comment: не могли бы помочь ещё с использованием функции usort
желательно, на моем примере, если можно
спасибо ^^